# Linux Keeps Operating after rm -rf --no-preserve-root /

Tags: linux, command, rm

I have done my search but couldn't find any answer.

After executing "**rm --no-preserve-root -rf /**", bash has told me things like:

- **rm: cannot remove /proc/*: Operation not permitted**
  ...
- **rm: cannot remove /etc: Device or resource busy**
  ...

Firstly, operation was clearly completed successfully since all files are deleted. If so why does it say such things?

Secondly, how can I still operate on my virtual CentOS machine when kernel(more like everything) is gone. Is there any kind of session that allows computer to keep operating?

Thirdly, system threw me to "**/**" directory in the end. When I called "**ll -a**", "**no such file or directory**". But if I call "**cd /etc**", bash lets me go there(!?). I even called "**cd ..**" and got back to "**/**".

I assume these have something to do with hardlinks and inodes but I have yet to find any clear explanation to this.

I don't want to be a "luser"(Introduction of Linux by Machtelt Garrels P.9) who haven't seen the light :(

Comment: "Completed successully" mean the program "continued" for you? Or did you check the exit code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some files and directories aren’t deleted, for various reasons indicated by the error messages you saw. `/proc` contents can’t be deleted; and any busy directory can’t be deleted either. However most of your system was deleted, including all the commands in `/bin`, `/usr/bin` etc.

The system continues operating because Linux, like other Unix-style systems, keeps files and directories as long as any process has them open. Deleting a file which is in use removes it from the directory, so it’s no longer visible, but any process already using it can continue to access it.

Running `ll -a` will produce an error, not because there are no files, but because `ls` is no longer available to run. To see what files are still there, run `echo *`; this is handled by the shell and will continue working, as is `cd` which also obviously still works for you.